# Pourquoi "le vin rosé" et non "rose"?

Tags: usage, étymologie

Comparer: "vin rouge", "vin blanc", mais "vin rosé", alors qu'on attendrait "vin rose". Pourquoi cette différence?

Comment: Les deux adjectifs *rose* et *rosé* n'ont pas le même sens. *Rose* c'est une couleur.  *Rosé* n'est pas une couleur, c'est une couleur X (blanc, beige, ocre, mauve, etc.) légèrement teintée de rose par un processus quelconque. « Rosé » c'est le participe passé du verbe « roser » (donner une coloration rose). 
Je suppose qu'on dit *rosé* pour le vin de cette dénomination parce qu'il est fait avec du jus de raisin à pulpe blanche, lequel est rosi par les pigments rouges contenus dans la peau (rouge) mise à macérer dedans pendant un temps bref et qui altère sa couleur.

Comment: @None Oui, mais alors pourquoi ne dit on pas « vin rougi » alors que le vin rouge est obtenu par le même procédé de macération, lequel ne résulte en un vin de couleur « rouge » que pour la seule raison qu'au lieu de laisser agir ce procédé pendant une courte période on prolonge son action pendant un temps beaucoup plus grand ?

Comment: @LPH En dehors de tout texte écrit expliquant pourquoi le premier qui a nommé une chose l'a nommé ainsi on ne peut que spéculer sur ses intentions, ce qui nous fait quitter l'étude de la langue. Du point de vue historique (et non pas linguistique) ce dont on est sûr c'est que l'existence du vin rosé est antérieure à celle du vin rouge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On peut trouver une explication linguistique à laquelle on peut ajouter des raisons d'ordre historique qui permettent de spéculer sur l'emploi du mot *rosé*.

Le premier point est **linguistique** : les deux adjectifs *rose* et *rosé* n'ont pas le même sens. *Rose* c'est une couleur. *Rosé* n'est pas une couleur, c'est une couleur X (blanc, beige, ocre, mauve, etc.) légèrement teintée de rose par un processus quelconque. « Rosé » c'est le participe passé du verbe « roser » qui veut dire donner une coloration rose.

Le deuxième point est **historique** : le premier vin de l'histoire était rosé. On trouve des représentations de l'antiquité (Égypte, Grèce, Rome) montrant à l'évidence la pratique de vinification en rosé. Le vin était fabriqué à partir de raisins noirs<sup>1</sup>, donc au départ on avait du jus blanc plus ou moins coloré par les pigments contenus dans la peau rouge. (*cf.* premier point).
C'est le *vinum clarum* des Romains qui a donné le *clairet* français du Moyen-Âge. La première apparition de l'adjectif *rosé* associé au vin date du 14<sup>e</sup> s., cité par [Jofroi de Waterford](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jofroi_de_Waterford) dans *Segré de segrez* et le terme réapparaît trois siècles plus tard, en 1680, dans le *Dictionnaire français* de [Pierre Richelet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar-Pierre_Richelet).

Le vin rouge étant d'apparition très récente.
Ce n'est qu'au 14<sup>e</sup> s. que la couleur du vin évolue du rosé vers le rouge avec la demande de vins contenant plus de tanins<sup>2</sup>. Ce n'est qu'au 19<sup>e</sup> s. que l’ensemble des vins de couleur claire s’est effacé au profit du rouge.

Peut-être (je ne fais que spéculer) peut-on voir dans la définition<sup>3</sup> de Pierre Richelet la réponse à pourquoi ne dit-on pas « vin rougi » pour le vin rouge : Richelet considérait que le rose n'était qu'une nuance de rouge.

---

**Sources** :
Article [vin rosé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin_ros%C3%A9#Le_%C2%AB_vinum_clarum_%C2%BB) de Wikipédia.
Article [vin rouge](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin_rouge#Pr%C3%A9histoire) de Wikipédia.
[*Le vin dans l'histoire*](https://www.larvf.com/,histoire,10374,1105513.asp#2), (la revue du vin de France).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Mis à part en Italie, il semble que les raisins aient été pendant des siècles très majoritairement de couleur noire.</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup> Les tanins sont contenus dans la peau et les pépins donc plus la macération est longue, plus le vin est riche en tanins.</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> [Rosé.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=f8VKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA409&lpg=PA409&dq=ros%C3%A9%20%22Pierre%20Richelet%22&source=bl&ots=kGYtHdZfSk&sig=ACfU3U3uOMrWjQk9zWfcD9cYeP4iNPDQLw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwityMKensnxAhWOxYUKHWPVAHYQ6AEwEnoECBIQAw#v=onepage&q=ros%C3%A9%20%22Pierre%20Richelet%22&f=false) *adj.* [*Vinum rubrum*] Qui ne se dit qu'au *masc.* & il se dit du vin. Il signifie que c'est d'un rouge agréable & tirant sur la couleur d'une rose d'un rouge vif.</sup>

Comment: On peut noter qu'en espagnol, vin rouge se dit *vino tinto* et que l'adjectif *tinto*, plutôt spécialisé aujourd'hui pour signifier rouge foncé, correspond au français "teint" (lat. *tinctus*).